# Call an object method inside setTimeout()

Tags: javascript

How can I call an object method inside `setTimeout` without losing the `this` binding?

```js
const bob = {
  name: 'Bob',
  greet: function () {
    console.log(`Hi, I'm ${this.name}`)
  }
};

bob.greet();                   // Hi, I'm Bob
setTimeout(bob.greet, 500);    // Hi, I'm
```

I know that in the `setTimeout` call, `this` is bound to the Window object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Hmm, I don't see it. I'm not using constructors, just an object literal.

Comment: It is the same principle. You want to refer to `this` (`this.name`) from within a callback (`bob.greet`). The solutions there also work for you

Comment: Bind the `this` scope with [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to the method object: `bob.greet.bind(bob)`

Comment: @Marc where do I put that?

Comment: See the link. bind returns a function, wich scope is bind to the object you pass to it. `setTimeout(bob.greet.bind(bob), 500);`

Comment: @Marc if you put it in an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a wrapper function like this:

```js
const bob = {
  name: 'Bob',
  greet: function () {
    console.log(`Hi, I'm ${this.name}`)
  }
};

bob.greet();
setTimeout(() => bob.greet(), 500);
```

MDN explains exactly this perfectly [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#the_this_problem)

Comment: Awesome answer, it helped me also to understand the lexical this of arrow functions. Thanks

Comment: @BobbyWan-Kenobi you welcome, I modified the answer, added an external link from MDN, 
explaining the `this` issue regarding `setTimeout`

Comment: You can even take away the curly braces to make it more compact ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have a scoping probleme here.

Use the [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method to set the `this` scope to the `bob` object:

```js
const bob = {
  name: 'Bob',
  greet: function () {
    console.log(`Hi, I'm ${this.name}`)
  }
};

bob.greet();                   // Hi, I'm Bob
setTimeout(bob.greet.bind(bob), 500);    // Hi, I'm
```

`.bind` returns a new function with the correct scope.

As an alternative solution, you can use a wrapper callback:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  bob.greet();
}, 500);
```

Notice the arrow function, which has no `this` scope: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [MDN] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

> " In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is
> called (runtime binding). It can't be set by assignment during
> execution, and it may be different each time the function is called.
> ES5 introduced the bind() method to set the value of a function's this
> regardless of how it's called, and ES2015 introduced arrow functions
> which don't provide their own this binding (it retains the this value
> of the enclosing lexical context)."

In addition to the method provided by Marc https://stackoverflow.com/a/67951749/14550472

an arrow function can also help

setTimeout(()=>{bob.greet()}, 500);